# C# BitArray save to or read from SQL Server Binary

Tags: c#, sql-server, bitarray

Current, converting c# `BitArray` to `byte[]` then save to SQL Server. Is there any way to save it directly?

```sql
var byteArray = new byte[625];
bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
Save(byteArray);
```

As reading from Binary to BitArray, using `byte[]` to receive the value and then converting to `BitArray`. Any way direct?

Comment: SQL Server stores Bit arrays packed as 8 bytes which is a byte array.  You may just need to  cast from one type to the other.

Comment: SQL Server 2022 (and Azure SQL Database) now also support various bit manipulation functions which work on the non-LOB binary type as well.  So, you can get and set bits, shift bit values, and count set bits in the SQL layer as needed.  Like jdweng says, you just cast in/out when converting from an app-tier concept like a bit array.  SQL does not have an array type as such.